# z3 endian-ness mixup between Extract and Concat

Tags: z3

I'm having difficultly understanding how endian-ness works in Z3 bit-vectors. Is it tied to the underlying CPU? I'm on an intel cpu, and Extract seems to work little-endian, as expected, however when Concat-ing the values the endian-ness seems reversed. For instance Concat(0xaa, 0xbb) produces 0xaabb and not the expected 0xbbaa (little endian, 0xaa is on the left so should be smallest)

The following code illustrates what I'm having problems with:

```
import z3

# running on intel os x, little-endian

s = z3.BitVecVal(0xbbaa, 16)
print( "s {}".format(hex(z3.simplify(s).as_long())) ) # 0xbbaa

# b1 and b2 are extracted little-endian, as expected

b1 = z3.Extract(7,  0, s)
b2 = z3.Extract(15, 8, s)
# 0xaa, first byte, smallest
print( "b1 {}".format(hex(z3.simplify(b1).as_long())) )
# 0xbb, second byte, biggest 
print( "b2 {}".format(hex(z3.simplify(b2).as_long())) ) 

# don't understand what is happening here, b1 is the left-most byte,
# should be smallest

j = z3.Concat(b1, b2)
print( "j {}".format(hex(z3.simplify(j).as_long())) ) 
# result 0xaabb position of bytes are reversed, 
# b2 (0xbb) is now smallest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z3 is simply following the SMTLib standard for bit-vectors here, which is architecture independent. See here for details: http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-FixedSizeBitVectors.shtml

In particular, `concat` is defined as follows:

```
[[(concat s t)]] := λx:[0, n+m). if (x < m) then [[t]](x) else [[s]](x - m)
   where
   s and t are terms of sort (_ BitVec n) and (_ BitVec m), respectively,
   0 < n, 0 < m.
```

This is a bit mouthful, but if you look into it the semantics clearly says the "lower" parts come from `t` and "upper" parts come from `s`.

Likewise, `extract` is defined as:

```
[[((_ extract i j) s))]] := λx:[0, i-j+1). [[s]](j + x)
   where s is of sort (_ BitVec l), 0 ≤ j ≤ i < l.
```

which essentially drops the first `j-1` bits and keeps up to the `i`th bit from then on.

Comment: thanks for the link to the standard, i didn't know that existed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have this figured out. It's not well documented anywhere, but z3 is big-endian. Bits are always indexed from the right, with 0 being the right-most, smallest bit. This explains the somewhat strange order of parameters to Extract ( Extract(high, low, from) ), as the "high" bit is actually to the left of the low bit.

Concat and Extract appear to have different endianess because Extract slices from the right to the left, where Concat builds the bit vector from left to right.

Comment: All vectors are encoded according to the SMT standard. If you like, you can assume big-endianness for all vectors. The extract instruction does not depend on endianness, it simply uses the same indexing that hardware languages like Verilog and VHDL use.